# How can I dynamically add a browser tab?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, iframe, dynamic, browser

Since using iframes to house external pages are, by some accounts "not the preferred method" and even disallowed by some sites (flickr, for one), I now want to dynamically generate browser tabs. e.g., when a user submits a form, I want to dynamically generate a tab on the browser in response to what is submitted. e.g., I might want to add a new tab with an URL like: http://www.bigsurgarrapata.com/contact

How to do this in jQuery?

Comment: Don't believe this can be done. Depends on the setting of the browser. Some users have their browsers set to open links in a new window, same window or new tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the form `target` attribute with the `action` attribute.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_target.asp

Browsers have ultimate control over the result of the target attribute but most will open a new tab with a value of _blank.

```
<form action="contact_submit.php" target="_blank" method="POST">
```

Comment: I want to open several, not just one. Other things will be going on on the main form/home page.

Answer (score 2):

You can open a new tab on submit I believe, just add

```
target="_blank"
```

to the html of the submit button.

Comment: This will only work if the user didn't change the browsers settings on how to handle new windows. - Firefox for example: http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/tab-preferences-and-settings